# bootstrap customize line-height for paragraph class

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap V4 and need for a customized paragraph a line-height of 1.
But I am not able to overright the bootstrap setting of ~1.5.

```
   <p class="ptime"><f:format.date format="H:i:s">{play.plDate}</f:format.date></p>
   <p class='dur'>{play.Duration}</p>

p.ptime {
    line-height:normal !important;
}
p.dur {
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height:normal !important;
}
```

I tried also 1, 1em for the line-height, but I am not able to reduce the space between the paragraphs (lines).

What I have to do?

Comment: None of the classes you used in your CSS selectors here, are actually present in the HTML you have shown.

Comment: And are you even talking about multiple lines in _one_ paragraph of text here? Your HTML code has _multiple_ paragraphs, and those presumably have default margins applied to them - sure it’s not actually that margin you want to remove?

Answer (score 0):

In default, bootstrap adds a `16px` margin at the bottom for every paragraph. So if you need to remove the space between those two paragraphs, you have to remove that bottom `margin` instead of reducing `line-height` using css.

From all the paragraphs,

```
p {
   margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

From only those two paragraphs (`ptime` & `dur` in your case)

```
.ptime, .dur {
   margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

See below working example. I used bootstrap `4.6.0`.

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p class="ptime">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, ullam inventore!    Officiis, quam facilis iste unde sapiente doloribus ad fugit quaerat nam natus, vero, ab totam! Provident perferendis nemo excepturi?
</p>      
<p class='dur'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At asperiores quas adipisci voluptas fuga dolore explicabo dolor labore delectus a incidunt dolorem accusamus beatae eveniet, quae, impedit excepturi ut sequi.
</p>
```